# What care does yucca need outdoors in New Hampshire?

Tags: plant-care

I live in New Hampshire and have a nice group of yucca plants on a hill. I am wondering how often they bloom and do I need to do anything special for it? It has bloomed twice but not last year. Do I need to provide more care?

Answer (score 2):

Nah yuccas are very low maintenance, just spit on them once in a while. JK but they have many similar properties as cacti, but just not to the same degree. I am from NH as well, they did not bloom last year because we got a ridiculous amount of rain.